# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED NGINX PROXY REVERSE

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having difficulty solving the problem that I'm not able to solve in days.

The problem is the error of ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I'm trying to access the api through the reverse proxy using subdomain.

I'm using Ubuntu.

Here is the configuration:

```
default:

    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /var/www/servicos.siteabc.org;
    server_name  servicos.siteabc.org;
    #server_name _ ;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

servicos.siteabc.org:

```
        [Unit]
    Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu
    [Service]
    WorkingDirectory=/var/www/servicos.siteabc.org
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/servicos.siteabc.org/TDWebApi.dll
    Restart=always
    # Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
    RestartSec=10
    KillSignal=SIGINT
    SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
    #User=root;
    Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

nginx.conf

        user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    
    events {
            worker_connections 768;
            # multi_accept on;
    }
    
    http {
    
            ##
            # Basic Settings
            ##
    
            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;
            # server_tokens off;
    
            # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
            # server_name_in_redirect off;
    
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;
    
            ##
            # SSL Settings
            ##
    
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
            ##
            # Logging Settings
            ##
    
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    
            ##
            # Gzip Settings
            ##
    
            gzip on;
    
            # gzip_vary on;
            # gzip_proxied any;
            # gzip_comp_level 6;
            # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            # gzip_http_version 1.1;
            # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    
            ##
            # Virtual Host Configs
            ##
    
            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
            client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
```

Apparently my services are running normally:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-10-22 17:32:00 UTC; 1h 21min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 275411 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 273065 (nginx)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 614)
     Memory: 10.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─273065 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─275412 nginx: worker process
             └─275413 nginx: worker process

Oct 22 17:32:00 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 22 17:32:00 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:21:19 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:21:19 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:23:21 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:23:21 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:25:44 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:25:44 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:30:51 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 22 18:30:51 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
root@siteabc:/var/www# sudo systemctl status servicostreed.service
● servicostreed.service - Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/servicostreed.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-10-22 16:59:37 UTC; 1h 53min ago
   Main PID: 271237 (dotnet)
      Tasks: 16 (limit: 614)
     Memory: 34.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/servicostreed.service
             └─271237 /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/servicos.siteabc.org/TDWebApi.dll

Oct 22 16:59:37 siteabc.org systemd[1]: Started Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu.
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]:       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]:       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]:       Hosting environment: Production
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Oct 22 16:59:39 siteabc.org dotnet-example[271237]:       Content root path:
```

Answer (score 0):

`error CONNECTION_REFUSE`D is for the cases that the service is not running on that specific port you are requesting. Use the command `ss -nltup` to get a list of all the available ports that are listening. I believe that the service is not running on port 5000.

Comment: I do not understand. It looks like it's normal:
tcp   LISTEN 0      128        127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:*     users:(("dotnet",pid=271237,fd=180))
tcp   LISTEN 0      128            [::1]:5000            [::]:*     users:(("dotnet",pid=271237,fd=181))

Comment: both nginx service and .net application are running on the same machine. and based on the things you posted above, you are not using containers, because you are using systemd, so please do a telnet to port 5000 on the machine to check weather your .net application is available or not. as you may notice your .net application is listening on 127.0.0.1 and that means it is only available on your machine not outside of it.

Comment: how do i check?

Comment: from the server you have nginx, do the command below:

        telnet localhost 5000
also it is better to check your nginx logs.

Comment: I managed to resolve it. I switched on proxy_pass to https  127.0.0.1:5001. Port 5000 doesn't work even with http I don't know why.